# How to convert string to dict and if same key appears twice then make its value as list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
s = 'o=foo t=bar t=baz f=zap'
```

How to convert this string into dict, but if same key is repeated, make it as list?

Expecting:

```
{'o': 'foo', 't': ['bar','baz'], 'f': 'zap'}
```

Tried:

```
>>> dict(token.split('=') for token in shlex.split(s))
{'o': 'foo', 't': 'baz', 'f': 'zap'}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function and pass a generator:

```
s = 'o=foo t=bar t=baz f=zap'
q = 'o=foo t=bar t=baz t=bop f=zap'

def dict_fromitems(items):

    d = dict()
    for (k, v) in items:
        if k in d:
            d[k] = (d[k] if type(d[k])==list else [d[k]]) + [v]
        else:
            d[k] = v
    return d

s_dict = dict_fromitems((i.split('=') for i in s.split()))
q_dict = dict_fromitems((i.split('=') for i in q.split()))
```

Returns:

```
{'o': 'foo', 't': ['bar', 'baz'], 'f': 'zap'}
{'o': 'foo', 't': ['bar', 'baz', 'bop'], 'f': 'zap'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the potential key value pair generated by splitting on `=` and check if the key is already present and check if the value is instance of `list` and if it is list append the value to it else create the list with the existing string value and append the value to it. If key is not present just create a new key with a value.

```
s = 'o=foo t=bar t=baz f=zap'

s_list=s.split()
d={}
for i in s_list:
    k,v=i.split('=')
    if k in d:
        if isinstance(d[k],list):
           d[k].append(v)
        else:
           d[k]=[d[k]]
           d[k].append(v)
    else:
        d[k]=v
print(d)
```

output:

```
{'f': 'zap', 'o': 'foo', 't': ['bar', 'baz']}
```